# Compile a C++ program in MacOS Catalina terminal, create an "executable". Run the "executable" in another computer in a MacOS terminal (stack here)

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, executable

I wrote a simple C++ code and compiled it in the terminal:

```
g++ main.cpp -o MyGame
```

I can execute it perfectly in the terminal:

```
./MyProgram
```

BUT I want to run this executable MyGame in my another computer MacOS (and I don't want to compile it again).  I tried to run ./MyGame in the terminal (in the correct folder), it didn't work. Appears a message of "permission denied". I tried sudo ./MyGame, used my password and it didnt work. I login as root and unfortunately it didn't work too...

Any help, please? Tks a lot.

Comment: It sounds like you have lost the executable permission bit on the file. Do `chmod 755 MyGame`, then try again.

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot!!